# Find the total of the sum of the first five terms of the arithmetic series and the sum of the first three terms of the geometric series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Following information is available regarding the series:

1. The second term of the geometric series is the same as the fourth
   term of the arithmetic series.
2. The $7^{th}$ term of the arithmetic series is the same as the $3^{rd}$ term of the geometric series.
3. The first term of the geometric series exceeds the first term of the
   arithmetic series by 64/3.
4. The sum of the first three terms of the
   arithmetic series, $A_3$ and the sum of the first two terms of the
   geometric series, $G_2$ are related by the formula $A_3 + G_2 + 21 =
   0$.

To find: The total of the sum of the first 5 terms of the arithmetic series and the sum of the first 3 terms of the geometric series.

My approach so far:

Let's assume that the first term of AP be $a$ and the common difference be $d$, the first term of GP be $b$ and the common ratio be $r$.
Then we have following:
$$br = a + 3d$$
$$br^2 = a + 6d$$
$$b-a=\frac{64}{3}$$
$$a+d+b+br+7=0$$

We have to find: $5a+10d+b+br+br^2$.

So far I have got:
$$a+d+b+br+7+br^2=a+6d \implies b+br+br^2=5d-7$$
Hence,
$$5a+10d+b+br+br^2=5a+10d+(5d-7)=5(a+3d)-7=5br-7$$

I am stuck at this point as I am not able to think of any way this can be solved without involving higher powers of the variables.

How can we proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** From $A_3+G_2+21=0$ we obtain $3a+3d+b+br+21=0$.

There are four equations in four variables and one of them contains $r^2$. So, you have to solve a quadratic equation as there is no nice cancellation.